# Cómo solucionar este error: you have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve command

Tags: angular

[image: Ese error obtengo al ejecutar ng serve, ejecuté npm install antes de eso.]

Investigando traté de investigar el angular cli local y obtengo esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. De forma simple para ejemplo; luego ejecutar (digamos el proyecto "tutorial") `ng new tutorial` debes entrar a ese directorio `tutorial` y ejecutar `ng serve`. No se aprecia los pasos previos que hiciste.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que estas corriendo el comando fuera del proyecto de angular. Pareciera que generaste un proyecto o instalaste las dependencias, pero no entraste la consola en la que estas corriendo el comando no se encuentra en la carpeta del proyecto

Comment: Si estaba en la ruta del proyecto, al parecer tenía inconvenientes con la versión de Node y no me permitía correr el sistema, igual gracias.